# Difference between loading frameworks from CDNs and from within server itself?

Tags: web

I am new to web development I wanted to know what is the difference between loading frameworks(jquery,bootstrap etc..)files via CDN's(Content delivery Networks) and linking the files from within the server?

Eg: for loading Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CDN will reduce page load times should the user already have a copy of the library cached locally. This comes with the risk that if the CDN is unavailable, the library wont be served.

Hosting it yourself will make sure that it's always available as long as your site is up.

Ideally you can do both, trying the CDN first and falling back to the version on your server.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='/js/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This would disallow the use of `async`, though. You could use manual script loading (which also avoids direct use of `document.write`, explicitly set the CDN load to be synchronous, and do you check there. Personally I'd prefer that method over this, e.g., http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/ It gets complicated.

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer using CDN because:

1. **Different domains**

Browsers limit the number of concurrent connections (file downloads) to a single domain. Most permit four active connections so the fifth download is blocked until one of the previous files has been fully retrieved. You can often see this limit in action when downloading many large files from the same site.

CDN files are hosted on a different domain. In effect, a single CDN permits the browser to download a further four files at the same time.

2. **Files may be pre-cached**

jQuery is ubiquitous on the web. There’s a high probability that someone visiting your pages has already visited a site using the Google CDN. Therefore, the file has already been cached by your browser and won’t need to be downloaded again.

3. **High-capacity infrastructures**

You may have great hosting but I bet it doesn’t have the capacity or scalability offered by Google, Microsoft or Yahoo. The better CDNs offer higher availability, lower network latency and lower packet loss.

4. **Distributed data centers**

If your main web server is based in Dallas, users from Europe or Asia must make a number of trans-continental electronic hops when they access your files. Many CDNs provide localized data centers which are closer to the user and result in faster downloads.

5. **Built-in version control**

It’s usually possible to link to a specific version of a CSS file or JavaScript library. You can often request the “latest” version if required.

6. **Usage analytics**

Many commercial CDNs provide file usage reports since they generally charge per byte. Those reports can supplement your own website analytics and, in some cases, may offer a better impression of video views and downloads.

7. **Boosts performance and saves money**

A CDN can distribute the load, save bandwidth, boost performance and reduce your existing hosting costs — often for free.

Resources:

1: https://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/

Comment: Please include a link to the source when copy pasting. https://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/